# How to check if bucket already exists in AWS S3 in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have bucket structure like below:

```
root/subfolder1/subfolder2/file1.txt
```

as per above structure there might be three cases possible:

1. root does not exist.
2. root exists but subfolder1 does not exist.
3. root and subfolder1 both  exist but subfolder2 does not exist.

I have to write program in python and need some flag based approach if bucket does not exists flag should turn from true to false or vice-versa .
Is there some apis in python to check all above scenarios in python ?

Comment: Have you tried to do yourself anything? Do you have any code to show and why it does not work?

Comment: yes I am trying option with bucket -exists and I have tried  if s3.Bucket('bucekt_name).creation_date is None  to validate above scenarios but I am exploring and doing pocs to check more better options.

Answer (score 2):

Using `boto3`:

```
    folder_name = 'folder_name'
    s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3")
    bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(
        settings.BUCKET
    )

    # Get file contents when the bucket is exists
    if bucket:
        objects = bucket.objects.filter(
            Prefix=f"{folder_name}/"
        )

        for obj in objects:
            # Get file contents
            response = obj.get()
            lines = response[u"Body"].read().decode("utf-8").split("\n")

            # Handle code here
            ...
    else:
        print(f"Bucket {settings.BUCKET} does not exist!")
        return
```

Answer (score 2):

In S3 a bucket is only `root` in your case. There is no concept of folders, instead each file is stored under a "link/key/path" (you can think of it as a long file name with "/" in it).

Knowing this everything you need to know that your bucket exists or not. After that you can just write your file using a specific key. There is no need to check if a part of a path exists or not. IF you want to avoid file override, then you can use `head` method to check it, see below.

To safely create a bucket:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.create_bucket

```
try:
  client.create_bucket(
    Bucket='root',
    CreateBucketConfiguration={
        'LocationConstraint': 'us-east-1',
    },
  )
except: # you can catch the specific error that boto3 throws when it already exists, I just don't remember what is this error.
  pass
```

To check if a file exists:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object

```
  try:
    client.head_object(
      Bucket="root",
      Key="/path/to/file/data.json"
    )
    return True
  except:
    return False
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Folders do not existing in Amazon S3. You can create an object in *any* path and it will work.

The Amazon S3 management console will make folders "appear" like normal, but they do not actually exist. For example, deleting the object will make the folders "disappear" (because they never actually existed).

The **Create Folder** button in the console actually creates a zero-length object with a Key (filename) equal to the full path of the folder. Deleting the zero-length object will make the folder disappear (but only if it is empty).

**Bottom line:** Don't concern yourself with whether folders exist. Just create the objects where you want them.